# Security considerations for encrypted home dir in case of an untrustworthy root

Tags: security, password, root, encryption, pam

Heiho,

although I have done some manual encrypting using various tools I consider myself a noob. Recently I worked on a tiny project utilizing PAM. Thereby it occurred to me that root can get hold of any user login passphrase in plain text as soon as the user logs in - basically without any effort for root or anyone with the privileges to edit `/etc/pam.d/system-login`.

In the light of root's power regarding the users' home dirs this might seem like a minor issue. But here I am not so much concerned with my user account in itself but with the encrypted data stored in it. Up until yesterday I felt quite secure with an encrypted home dir, believing that only my passphrase can unlock it. But if I do this via automount at login, root might catch the passphrase and mount it anytime. I wouldn't take notice of that.

I wonder how much of an issue this is. Although I don't store any sensible data on a system with an untrustworthy root, this doesn't apply to everybody. A quick search shows that there is surprisingly little concern about it and I doubt that this is commonly known. [The Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EncFS#Mount_at_login_using_pam_encfs)   says you should use a strong passphrase when automounting your encrypted home dir. The hash is written to `/etc/shadows` and if someone gets hold of it they might deduce a weak passphrase from the hash and decrypt your home. To my eyes this misses the point - at least in practical terms: Those who gain access to `/etc/shadows` probably can also manipulate PAM and therefore get your super strong passphrase as soon as you log into system the next time. [This Thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36044/can-we-know-the-password-for-the-other-users-if-we-have-root-access) also falls short of the issue. PAM is mentioned, but rather vaguely. Nowhere did I find a hint to the worrisome link between passphrase visibility and the vulnerability of encryption.

Am I right to state that everything I do with my login-passphrase can't be hidden from the eyes of an evil root? Is an additional encryption layer with a passphrase different from the login passphrase indispensable?  And is it sufficient? In retrospect using two different passphrases makes sense since two different task are at hand. But consider how widely automounting is used, i. e. how often this principle is violated. Usually this is even the default setup.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I right to state that everything I do with my login-passphrase can't be hidden from the eyes of an evil root?

Yes, and the same goes for everything else on the box, period. (Except maybe really obscure, impractical things like SGX.)

> Is an additional encryption layer with a passphrase different from the login passphrase indispensable?

Doesn't matter, because of the next part.

> And is it sufficient?

No.

If someone evil has root, then they can see and modify all data that you can on that machine. In this case, they could install a keylogger to capture your second passphrase too, or `su` to you after you mount it, or use a debugger to hijack one of your processes, etc. In general, if someone evil has root on your machine, it's not your machine anymore. You should make security decisions around trying to keep attackers from getting root, not around futile attempts to limit the damage they can do after getting root.

Comment: Jep, as bad as I suspected. At least, I don’t have to worry about additional security measures apart from a strong passphrase (on such a machine) since they won’t do anything to protect me in this scenario.